# Minimum permissions to inject Chrome Extension content script

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Custom Dev Panel Extension (similar to Vue JS Dev tools) and can inject a content script using this code.

```
//background.js   
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file: "js/contentdebugger.js"});
```

My permissions are.

```
"permissions": [
  "activeTab",
  "<all_urls>"
],
```

I only want to inject the code when I have opened my custom dev pane for a page. I don't want to publish with the <all_urls> permissions (Google warns the review process is more stringent) but if I remove the <all_urls>, it fails with this message in the background page.

"Unchecked runtime.lastError: Cannot access contents of the page. Extension manifest must request permission to access the respective host."

Everything I've read and the Chrome docs state "Host permissions can either be granted either by requesting them as part of your extension's manifest (see host_permissions) **or temporarily via activeTab**."

I have activeTab in the permissions but I always get the error.

What am I missing/what are the minimum permissions to inject the script?

Comment: Use chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval with useContentScriptContext:true. As for activeTab, it needs an explicit user gesture.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've got a couple of [questions](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-extensions/c/iNiHf5lVE9k) in the forum, too long to fit here. Not sure if you have a moment to respond.

Comment: This API is not related to JS eval() - to address one of the concerns.

Comment: Yes, understood on eval. It's more around having to write a new way to handle frames (when I thought I was done and frames are rather tedious to take care of) and getting the content script injected with serialized variables and the like.